# What should be considered when migrating Liferay from Oracle to MySQL?

Tags: mysql, oracle, migration, liferay

We are currently running Liferay 6.0.6 connected to Oracle 11.2.0.2.0.  Due to business requirements around licensing of Oracle I need to investigate moving this over to MySQL 5.5 with InnoDB.  Downtime will be acceptable for this migration.

- Can I just copy code and data structure over?
- Would a new installation with MySQL be best, and then copy data over from the Oracle installation?
- Has anyone here done this before?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the side of migrating the database, the easiest way to do this is to go to the ControlPanel, under Server Administration you'll find a page with a Database migration UI. This will read from your current database (e.g. oracle) and write to a database that you configure on that UI. Make sure that nobody is accessing the portal during that time - this feature has been created specifically for migrating databases: There might be some differences between the databases, that will automatically be "translated" in this progress.

On a somewhat related side note: If you want to get updates and fixes (including security), you should consider to upgrade to a maintained version, CE or EE. 6.0 CE (which is what 6.0.6 is) has end-of-lifed a while ago. 6.0 EE is still available, as well as 6.1 CE and EE.

Edit in 2017: Note that this feature is no longer supported in Liferay 7 and DXP: The database migration tool doesn't cover (all of) the module's tables.